# How to dynamically update table based on selecting a single data point on a time series graph

Tags: data-visualization, apache-superset, graph-visualization

I currently have set up Superset Apache to have two visualizations, one being a Time Series Graph and the other being a table. Both visualizations are using the same dataset. I want the values of the table to be dynamically updated based on which data point I am hovering over/selecting in the Time Series Graph. Is this type of functionality possible in Superset Apache? I know it is possible in Power BI but I'd like to know if Superset is capable of accomplishing this as well.

(As far as I can tell right now, it seems like each visualization is independent. The only time the visualizations are linked is when there is a filter applied from a filter visualization which affects the overall dataset)